# NB regression and LAG variable X

Tags: regression, time-series, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm doing a time series analysis, and I want to fit a negative binomial regression model.

I did a GRANGER analysis that told me that the LAG of X explains Y better than the LAG of Y. And in the problem it makes sense.

So I performed the LAG of X and the present value of X in the model, and only the present value of X is significant. If I remove the present value of X, the LAGS become significant. And it is difficult to explain that the present value of X increases Y, as the logic is that increasing X in the past would lead to an increase in Y.

I'm not sure if I'm breaking the model's assumptions  removing the present value and working only with LAG.